# How to allow spaces in directories when using find -exec together with basename?

Tags: find, exec, whitespace

I'm trying to find all the directories in a given path, and create soft links inside those directories into directories with the same names at another location. Many of the directories have spaces in their names. I have cobbled the following code together, and it seems to work provided there are no spaces.

```
find /some/path/* -maxdepth 0 -exec sh -c "ln -s /some/other/path/"'$(basename {})'" {}" \;
```

How should I change this to handle spaces? I normally don't have them in my directory names, but these mirror directories on my Windows PC, where I do use spaces. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

In response to the points made by cuonglm and Gilles:

- The order of the `ln -s` command arguments is not mistaken, but what I wanted to do is not quite clear from my explanation. For every directory in `/some/path/`, I want to create a symbolic link *in* that directory pointed at a directory with the same name in `/some/other/path/`. So `/some/other/path/` is the `source`, and `/some/path/` is the `destination`. The reason I want to do this is because `/some/path/` contains a subset of the directories in `/some/other/path/`, and I want a link from the subset to the full set for every directory.
- There won't be too many directories in the path, but I agree that not guarding against it is a pointless flaw.
- The reason I didn't use `-type d` is that there will only be directories and not files in the given path, but I realise including it is better.

Comment: How come this works? You are taking file names from `/some/path/*` and try to create symbolic links in place of those very files - second argument of `ln -s`. You will surely get `File exists` error.

Comment: I don't know. As I'm sure is obvious, I am really a novice when it comes to linux. Can ln -s be taking the second argument as the path to create the link in? It does appear there, and with the same name as the directory it's in.

Comment: @techraf This indeed seems to be the case. In fact, if I specify a non-existing path, like `/some/path/test` and run the `ln -s` command twice, then the first link will be `/some/path/test`, but the second will be `/some/path/test/target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some issues with your command:

- `/some/path/*` can cause argument list too long error if there're too many directories under `/some/path`
- It does not filter directory or file
- It's very in-efficient because it used inline-script `sh -c` but with `-exec ... {} \;`
- Using `ln` with wrong argument position, `ln -s source dest` will create symbolic link from `source` to `dest`, not `dest` to `source`.

---

You can do it POSIXly:

```
find /some/path ! -path /some/path -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    ln -s "$f" /some/other/path/"${f##*/}"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Or if your `find` supports `-maxdepth`:

```
find /some/path -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you! However, the order I need to use is definitely `ln -s dest source`. I had a look at `man ln`, and I think the only way to get the other order is if you write `ln -s -t source dest`. Also, the paths I use will not have very many directories, and there will only be directories and no files. However, that part of your solution is still much better practice. I will edit my question to reflect this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MartinBoström No, I assure you, it's `ln -s source destination`, where `source` is the (usually existing) target of the link and `destination` is the path to the link to create.

Comment: @Gilles I see my mistake now, and the source of the confusion. I meant the same thing, but mixed up `source` and `destination` because I was thinking of the directory the link points to as the `destination`. However, the order I put the terms in in the question is right (but with poorly chosen words) because what I want to do is this: if a directory exists in `/some/path`, make a link in that directory to a directory with the same name in `/some/other/path`. This is obviously neither clear, nor a normal thing to want to do. I will edit my question to clarify this. Apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

First, always use `{}` as a separate argument in `find -exec …`. Using `stuff{}morestuff` works with some (not all) versions of `find`, but cannot possibly cope with filenames containing “unusual” characters such as whitespace, `'`, `"`, etc. (exactly which characters cause trouble depends on exactly where you use `{}`). Pass `{}` as a separate argument. The first argument after `sh -c CODE` is `$0`. [Don't forget the double quotes around variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters?s=2|0.6167).

```
find … -exec sh -c 'ln -s /some/other/path/$(basename "$0") "$0"' {} \;
```

(I also simplified the quoting to use single quotes throughout.)

There is at least one other problem with your command. You're attempting to create a symbolic link at the location returned by `find`, where by construction there's already a symbolic link. It seems that you intended to create a symbolic link under `/some/other/path`, in which case you need to swap the arguments to `ln` (like with `mv` and `cp`, the existing file(s) come first, and the destination comes last).

```
find /some/path/* -maxdepth 0 -exec sh -c 'ln -s "$0" /some/other/path/$(basename "$0")' {} \;
```

You can make this faster by using shell string manipulation constructs instead of `basename`, and by invoking `sh` in batches at a time.

```
find /some/path/* -maxdepth 0 -exec sh -c '
  for x do
    ln -s "$x" /some/other/path/${x##*/};
  done' {} +
```

If that's your actual `find` command, then `find` isn't useful here. The point of `find` is to recurse into subdirectories. A non-recursive find can sometimes be useful to take advantage of its filters (e.g. to act only on files of a certain type or modified within a certain time span). But a non-recursive `find` with no filtering is pointless.

```
for x in /some/path/*; do
  ln -s "$x" "/some/other/path/${x##*/}";
done' {} +
```

Or

```
cd /some/path
for x in *; do
  ln -s "$PWD/$x" "/some/other/path/$x";
done' {} +
```

Alternatively, with [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zln):

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zln='zmv -L'
zln -s '/some/path/*' '/some/other/path/$f:t'
```

Comment: This post is very educational for someone as inexperienced with Linux as myself. Thank you!